# fancybox conditional width depends on its "Type"

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, fancybox-2

I'm showing **images** and **pdfs** using same **fancybox initialization**, created and initialized as :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="/path/to/imageORpdf" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Step : ${status.count }">
    Step : ${status.count }
</a>
```

```js
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
  'width': '90%',
  'height': '100%',
  'transitionIn': 'elastic',
  'transitionOut': 'elastic',
   type: 'iframe',
   cyclic:   true,
});
```

Without `type='iframe'` images opens with original size, but it does not work for `pdf`.
With `type='iframe'` to show **pdf**, then images open in `iframe` but with extended **iframe** size.

I want to open **images** as original size and **pdf** with `width='90%'`.
How to do this ?

I'm using fancybox 2.1.5 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by following changes :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="/path/to/imageORpdf"  data-fancybox-group="gallery"  title="Step : ${stepStatus.count }"
        ${ ( fn:split(uploadedFiles[stepStatus.index],'.')[1] ) eq 'pdf' ? 'data-fancybox-type=iframe' : '' }
        >
        Step : ${stepStatus.count }
</a>
```

I have decided type of fancybox at element itself using a condition as ::

```
${ ( fn:split(uploadedFiles[stepStatus.index],'.')[1] ) eq 'pdf' ? 'data-fancybox-type=iframe' : '' }
```

since I'm using jsp i used EL Expression to check it.

And  Here is my Fancybox configuration ::

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    'width' : '90%',
    'height' : '100%',
    'autoSize' : false,
    fitToView: false,
    'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
    cyclic    :   true,
});
```